# htaccess file to hide subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm struggling with the .htaccess file. I've wordpress installed in a subdirectory 'wordpress'. In the root folder if have the htaccess with the following content:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ /wordpress%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Redirection is working, but how can I hide the subfolder 'wordpress'?

THX in advance

EDIT: Tried following content now but still not working:

root htaccess:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

wordpress htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT2: my whole root htaccess looks like this now:

```
Allow from all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If i type in [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) I am redirected to example/wordpress/home, example/wordpress/contact and so on...

I would like to hide the wordpress directory like example/home, example/contact and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Redirection is working, but how can I hide the subfolder 'wordpress'?

You shouldn't be "redirecting". You should be internally rewriting the request instead. Remove the `R` flag.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule !^wordpress/ wordpress%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

The slash prefix on the *susbtitution* string is also not required.

This assumes you have the standard WP `.htaccess` file in the `/wordpress` subdirectory.

**UPDATE:** Also confirm you have removed the `/wordpress` subdirectory from the "Website Address" and "Site Address" in WordPress General settings.

Comment: Sorry for my late response... i tried it out but is still not working :-( I updated the content of root htaccess and wordpress htaccess in the first post... Can you please have a look again?

Comment: @opitzh What do you mean by "not working" exactly? An error? Still redirecting? Nothing? Note that you will need to make sure that all intermediary/browser caches are cleared since the earlier 301 (permanent) redirect will be cached persistently. You'll also need to configure WordPress to remove the `/wordpress` path segment from the generated URLs.

Comment: _Aside:_ You don't need the `<IfModule>` wrapper in the root `.htaccess` file. `Order` and `Allow` directives are older Apache 2.2 directives and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 (which you are more likely to be using) - do you need these anyway? @opitzh

Comment: The subfolder 'wordpress' is still shown in the url... Is it somehow possible to hide the wordpress path? I will try to remove the IfModule and check if it is working... THX

Comment: @opitzh Are you saying you are still being "redirected"? Presumably you are linking to the URL without `/wordpress`?

Comment: Please see my edit2 section in the question

Comment: Have you made sure your browser cache is cleared? After the update there is no code in `.htaccess` that would trigger this redirect, so if it's not a cached redirect then WordPress itself would seem to be do this (you can check this by looking at the HTTP response headers in the browser dev tools). Where is `home` coming from? Only WP would know about that. Your update also implies the www subdomain is lost through the redirect? There is nothing in `.htaccess` that is doing that either. What are the "Website Address" and "Site Address" set to in WordPress General settings?

Comment: You can implement a redirect in `.htaccess` to remove "wordress" from the URL. However, if WP itself is redirecting to add it then it will create a redirect loop. @opitzh

Comment: Holy S***, I forgot to remove the wordpress from the url in the wordpress settings... now it works like a charm. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: @opitzh You're welcome. I've added that nugget of info to complete my answer. Please also consider upvoting answers/questions you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)